# Pig Script to parse and compute cumulative value

Tags: parsing, apache-pig

Input file with two column:

```
Visit   ProductString
101      ;Cross Trainers;1;69.95,;Athletic Socks;10;29.99
102      ;Amplifier;1;120.90,;Headphone;2;59.99;leather wallet;1;99.99;
```

I am looking for Pig script that can parse "ProductString" value in each row and provide cumulative revenue.

```
ie.,Output:
69.95+29.99+120.90+59.99+99.99=380.82
```

Comment: In product string, I see revenue ending with , in few places. Is this how it is ? eg : 69.95, 120.90, ...

Comment: @MuraliRao - Correct! Comma (",") is the delimiter for each product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume there should be a `,` after `59.99` and that there shouldn't be a `;` after `99.99`.  If so, you need to `tokenize` and `flatten` on the `,` to extract products and then split on the `;` to get item prices and qty.

**Query**:

```
data = LOAD 'db.table';
A = FOREACH data GENERATE visit, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(product_string, ',')) AS tmp_col;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE visit, STRSPLIT(tmp_col, ';') AS prod;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE visit, prod.$1 AS item:chararray
    , (int)prod.$2 AS qty:int, (double)prod.$3 AS revenue:double;
grpd = GROUP C all;
D = FOREACH grpd GENERATE SUM(C.revenue);
DUMP D;
```

**Output**:

```
(380.82)
```